# Why am I getting notifications about someone I have blocked on Twitter

Tags: twitter

I get emails from Twitter for notifications, so the other day I notice I got an email about a notification from Twitter about someone I have blocked what they tweeted! Does anyone know why I’m getting notifications about someone I have blocked?

Answer (score 0):

Per Twitter's [Help Center:](https://help.twitter.com/en/using-twitter/blocking-and-unblocking-accounts)

> You will not receive notifications from accounts you block

However, there are some reasons why blocked accounts may show up in your notifications:

> 1. Tweets from others you follow that mention accounts you have blocked.
> 2. Tweets that mention you, along with an account you have blocked.

If you've already checked to be sure you didn't accidentally unblock the user, one of the above reasons may be the case here. Without knowing the full context, it's impossible to say for sure.

If you don't believe the above scenarios apply, you can always [contact Twitter](https://help.twitter.com/en/contact-us) to let them know about the issue.